# Unable to view the component descriptor editor in UIMA Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, uima

I have installed the UIMA and integrated it with eclipse as per the instructions on the website. But, even after I placed the plugins inside eclipse, when I go to the xml file under descriptors->tutorial->ex1->TutorialTypeSystem.xml, I cannot open it with the component descriptor editor because I don't see that options when I right click on it.

Comment: Sounds like the plugin didn't install, or could not activate for the version you have. What version of UIMA/Eclipse are you using? Is it only missing that, or is other functionality missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the Eclipse update site instead of manually putting the Jars in.